# Logging from Bootstrap mode?

Tags: plugin-development, bootstrap-craft, logging

We've been using bootstrap.php to have a basic PHP file run parts of some content-sync from a plugin we've written.

The sync is run from cron and this works great.

BUT - when the sync runs from the bootstrapped file - there are no logging info stored. I.e. the sync code works fine, but nothing is logged to: `craft/storage/runtime/logs/<pluginname>.log` - when triggering the sync from within the CP as a full-craft request, logging works fine.

Is there a way to get the bootstrap app to setup logging, so that logging from my plugin would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing it from a custom bootstrap script, you'd need to do something like this for plugin logging to work:

```
$craft = require '../craft/app/bootstrap.php';

craft()->plugins->loadPlugins();
MyPlugin::log('My Message', LogLevel::Error);
craft()->end();
```

Comment: Ah - I did the loadPlugins, but not `craft()->end();` was missing, thanks Brad!

Comment: Logs don't get flushed until the `onEndRequest` event fires, which `craft()->end()` will do for you.

Comment: not really related to this question - but sometimes I have longer running processes - and I'd like to flush the logs sooner - is there something you can call to flush them mid-request?

Comment: @gromgull - Yup... wanna post that as a new question?

Comment: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9446/flushing-logs-halfway-through-a-request :)