# Flushing logs halfway through a request?

Tags: plugin-development, logging

Sometimes I have long running requests that do imports or similar.

Currently logging using `MyPlugin::log` is only actually written to file once the request is done.

Is there a way to trigger log-flushing mid-request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that with something like this:

```
Craft::getLogger()->flush();
```